# jQuery animation using variable

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-animate

I have written a script to slide a div horizontally and stop at a specific margin-left value.

The margin left depends on the link which was clicked, so I have used a calculation to find that specific value. When i try to pass the variable into the .animate({"margin-left":value},"slow");

Here is the code

```
    var marginLeft = parseInt((linkClick * 995)-995)+"px";
    $("div_to_animate").animate({
      "margin-left":marginLeft},"slow");
```

I have used the code below to ensure that it is returning the correct value

```
alert(marginLeft);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: And what's your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector you use in your example code isn't correct.  If your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="div_to_animate">...</div>
```

Your selector should be:

```
$("#div_to_animate").animate({"margin-left":marginLeft},"slow");
```

Comment: sorry, that CSS selector was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I needed to add a "-" symbol before the marginLeft variable to make it a negative margin.

Thanks for the advice.